# how to synchronise room database of android app with remote server

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, synchronization, android-room

I'm working on an android app with an MVVM pattern. I have to sync my local database with a remote server. but I have no idea how to do it. I have used the room database.

Comment: You could check out Firebase, it is free and easy to set up. https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.